# Two way data binding in a directive without an isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive which needs to work alongside a directive which uses an isolated scope. This, of course, raises this error:

```
Multiple directives asking for new/isolated scope
```

My code looks roughly like this:

HTML:

```
<p custom_directive='variable' vendor_directive>Test</p>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('ExampleDirective',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            exampleDirective: '='
        },
        link: function(scope,element,attributes){
            // manipulate scope.exampleDirective
        }
    }

    });
```

I have already tried removing the scope completely from my directive and using something along the following:

```
scope.exampleDirective = scope.$eval(attributes.exampleDirective)
```

However, this only appears to work on objects, whereas I'm targeting other types of variables.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Use the [$parse service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) to create both setter and getter functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I can see here is that vendor_directive has already created an isolated scope so angular is not allowing you to define another isolated scope in same digest cycle. There are two ways to solve this problem -

- First and more complicated one is that you decorate the vendor directive to include the functionality of your custom directive. This is more stable and trustable way. Go through the documentation of decorators here [decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators)
- Second and easy way is to use $watcher on attributes.exampleDirective variable and execute a function everytime it changes so it will mimic the two way binding you desire

Hope this helps

Comment: A decorator is really a no go in this case since these two directives will not always be together, I just need to address it *when* they are. As for your second solution, I can't $watch them since they're just strings instead of bindings at this point, and they never change.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
app.directive('ExampleDirective',function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    bindToController: {
        exampleDirective: '='
    },
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope,element,attributes) {
        // manipulate scope.exampleDirective
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What should be in the directive's controller for this to work?